# Django letting user filter objects with form

Tags: python, django

So I have object instances in the model and I would like to allow users to filter through them based on certain characteristics. I setup a form and added some code to handle it in the view. When the form is submitted it returns the same template but with the object filters they set. However it is not working... I was wondering why/how I should go about doing this.

From:

```
class PropertySearchForm(forms.Form):
    beds = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control mb-3'}, choices=BED_CHOICES))
    baths = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control mb-3'}, choices=BATH_CHOICES))
```

View:

```
def UniversityHomePageView(request,name_initials):
    university = get_object_or_404(University,name_initials=name_initials)
    listings = Listing.objects.filter(l_university=university)
    form = PropertySearchForm(request.GET or None)
    company = Company.objects.filter(c_university=university)

    context = {
            'listings':listings,
            'university':university,
            'company':company,
            'form':form,
            }

    if form.is_valid():
        beds = int(form.cleaned_data.get('beds'))
        baths = int(form.cleaned_data.get('baths'))
        listings = Listing.objects.filter(l_university=university,beds=beds,baths=baths)

        return render(request,'listings/university_homepage.html',context)

    return render(request,'listings/university_homepage.html',context)
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working - are you checking the form is valid (does that block even run?) and you're not just jumping straight to returning the template without the updated context so it just looks like it's not applying filtering and you think it should?

Comment: Yes, I think that's what is happening. it states this when I hit submit `[31/Dec/2017 19:54:26] "POST /tu/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9813`

Comment: If that block is running, then you need to update the `listings` object inside your `context` object. Doing `listing = ` there binds a new name to a new queryset object and doesn't have any effect on the listings object already in your dictionary. You need to do `context['listings'] = listings` to update to use the new listings.

Comment: So this `context['listings'] = Listing.objects.filter(l_university=university,beds=beds,baths=baths)` Inside the if statement? If that's not right can you post an answer showing what you're saying?

Comment: Yup that's along the right lines... You can just re-use the existing listings such as listings.filter(beds=beds, bathrooms=bathrooms) if you wanted though.

Comment: Like this: `context['listings'] = Listing.objects.filter(listings,beds=beds,baths=baths)` It still doesn't change what gets displayed to the user

Comment: No - not like that and that would have caused an error so looks like your form isn't validating - put some print statements in your view and make some requests... Also if the form is making a post request you want to take things from request.POST instead of GET

Comment: @JonClements It works, if you submit that in an answer I'll up vote and accept it. Thank you.